# Order CSS in header menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to move a Website from TYPO3 to Wordpress. My site is almost done, but there's a problem with the header menu. My header is supposed to have a darker background when clicking on a specific page on the original website. On my testing website on WordPress the background gets darker only on the front page.

This is what the background looks like when you access the original website and my testing website:

[image: front page background]

and this is what it should look like when clicking on "Angebote" next to "Home":

[image: second page background]

But instead, it stays the same as for the first picture, although it's showing the right content.

Since I've been designing the website to my likings I had to use the inspector tool to fix some mistakes, so I did that in this case as well, but I can't find out how to order the background color on the different pages. I've looked into the HTML code as well. Since the header menu is self-made I couldn't look it up.

This is a part of the HTML code for the header menu:

```css
ul.navigationboxL {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 700px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  /*background-color: #00E12D;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f7f7f7+0,eaeaea+54,c4c4c4+100,8ea6a2+100,829d98+100,4e5c5a+100,4e5c5a+100,4e5c5a+100 */
  background: #f7f7f7;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #eaeaea 54%, #c4c4c4 100%, #8ea6a2 100%, #829d98 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #eaeaea 54%, #c4c4c4 100%, #8ea6a2 100%, #829d98 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f7 0%, #eaeaea 54%, #c4c4c4 100%, #8ea6a2 100%, #829d98 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%, #4e5c5a 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#4e5c5a', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="Headermenubox">
  <ul class="navigationboxL">
    <li><a class="aktuell" title="Home" href="http://ten.nis">| Home</a></li>
    <li><a title="Angebote" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=29">| Angebote</a></li>
    <li><a title="Sponsoring" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=31">| Sponsoring</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I tried messing with the CSS on the inspector tool which didn't work. Any kind of help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is not the full css!

Comment: No, it's not. The header has two menus, but the other one is for emails and printing. The website is https://www.promotennis.ch. This is the full css for Firefox: view-source:https://www.promotennis.ch/StyleSheet.css

Comment: It works for their site. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the background doesn't cange for the other elements like "Angebote" or "Sponsoring" on my test website.

Comment: Because they probably have some JavaScript there that does the stuff. You need to copy that too.

Comment: Is there any way to copy that code with the inspector tool? I'm not the owner of the original site.